# Remove Unnecessary Tags from Html string in c#

Tags: c#, html, regex, ihtmlstring

I am getting this Html string from system

```html
<h1>PDF Attachment</h1>
<h1 style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); text-align: center;">
  <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;">Your service detail are following</p><p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;">
    <table>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>&nbsp;
    <br>
 </p>
 <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;">  
   <br>
 </p>
</h1>
```

I have two h1 tags in this string. I want to remove "h1" tag in which "table" tag is used.

How can i remove it programmatically?

Comment: Probably off topic, but I must warn you that due to the errors in this HTML, the table would not be inside the paragraph when you view this in a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://html-agility-pack.net/):

```
var content = @"<h1>PDF Attachment</h1><h1 style=""color: rgb(51, 51, 51); text-align: center;""><p style=""font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;"">Your service detail are following</p><p style=""font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;""><table><tr><td></td></tr></table>&nbsp;<br></p><p style=""font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;""><br></p></h1>";

HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(content);
var h1NeedsToRemove = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/h1").Where(i => i.ChildNodes.Any(c => c.Name == "table")).FirstOrDefault();
var childNodesOfH1 = h1NeedsToRemove.ChildNodes;
h1NeedsToRemove.Remove();

htmlDoc.DocumentNode.AppendChildren(childNodesOfH1);
```

It will give you desired output:

```
<h1>PDF Attachment</h1>
<p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;">Your service detail are following</p><p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;">
    <table>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>&nbsp;
    <br>
 </p>
 <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;">  
   <br>
 </p>
```

Comment: but i need this output

<h1>PDF Attachment</h1>
  <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;">Your service detail are following</p><p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;">
    <table>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>&nbsp;
    <br>
 </p>
 <p style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400; text-align: justify;">  
   <br>
 </p>

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks :)
Just want to ask one more thing that how can i select multiple nodes like h1 or h2?

Comment: You can use `ToList()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: It removed closing tag of "p" automatically :(

Comment: i want to ask like this "htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/h1,/h2")". i want both h1 and h2 nodes.